# Project not commiting to github correctly

Tags: git, github, egit

When I commit a project to the remote github repository by right clicking on the project and selecting "push", a new project folder is created with same name as project folder that I created on github. So in github I then have two folders with the same name as shown :

[image]

The source code should be directly below "mark", not below "mark" -> "mark". How can I commit the source code to the remote repository without creating a new project directory in the remote repository ?
The structure in attached image should be

```
 `"mark" -> ".settings","src","war",".classpath",."project"`
```

instead of

```
"mark" -> "mark" -> ".settings","src","war",".classpath",."project"
```

Note : The whitespace between the names "mark" is because I removed part of the repository name.

Comment: Is your repository's directory structure not that way locally?

Comment: No, I have a top level project named "mark" and all of my source code is directly below it. Maybe when I commit a project I should commit the source files instead of comitting the the project itself ?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. When you do a fresh clone of the repository in another directory are the folders wrong? If anything this would be a GitHub bug, but Git reflects exactly what you have committed, and doesn't make folders in the repo that aren't physically there.

Comment: Please add which GUI you are using. It will be a lot easier to understand the problem then.